# Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(_) throws -> ()' to non-throwing function type '(Response) -> Void'

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling

I need to handle the api error codes like this and throw error  for some status code. But follow code shows the above error. how can i achieve this?

```
func login(data: [String: Any], completion: @escaping (ResponseModel<SignUpModel>?) -> Void) throws {
        NetworkAdapter.request(target: .login(data: data), success: { (response) in

            if let responseModel =  try? JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseModel<SignUpModel>.self,from: response.data) {
                switch responseModel.statusCode {
                case 2000:
                    completion(responseModel)
                case 4005:
                    throw ValidationError.athenticationFailure
                case .none,.some:
                    break
                }
                completion(responseModel)
            } else {
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot

```
throw ValidationError.athenticationFailure
```

because the request is asynchronous. What you can do is to change the completion type to `Result<ResponseModel<SignUpModel>, ValidationError>` to return

```
completion(.success(responseModel))
```

on success and

```
completion(.failure(athenticationFailure)
```

on failure. By the way I buy an `u`

**Update**:

Meanwhile – with Swift Concurrency – you are able to throw errors using a `ThrowingContinuation`

```
func login(data: [String: Any]) async throws -> ResponseModel<SignUpModel> {
    withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
        NetworkAdapter.request(target: .login(data: data), success: { (response) in
            do {
                let responseModel =  try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseModel<SignUpModel>.self,from: response.data)
                switch responseModel.statusCode {
                    case 2000:
                        continuation.resume(returning: responseModel)
                    case 4005:
                        continuation.resume(throwing: ValidationError.athenticationFailure)
                    case .none,.some:
                        continuation.resume(returning: responseModel)
                }
            } catch {
                continuation.resume(throwing: error)
            }
        })
    }
}
```